# TD Height varies between Browsers?

Tags: html, cross-browser, html-table

I have been trying to get an SVG element to fill the available space within a table cell. In Google Chrome the table cell's height is equal to the content height of the tallest table cell in its containing row. However in Internet Explorer the table cell's height simply takes-on the height of its own content with no regard for taller siblings in the same row. The table cells of both Chrome and Internet Explorer look the same (i.e. they are neatly squared) but the underlying height attributes are only actually equal in Chrome.

Does anyone know if this is a bug in Internet Explorer?

Any assistance will be gratefully received.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding reset.css at the top of your css file [reset.css](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/)

Also you can try using normalize.css at the top of your css file [normalize.css](http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/)

May be that can help you!!

Answer (score 0):

if it does try adding !important when you set the height of the TD in css 
ex:

```
td{
height:150px !important;
}
```

this prevent any override to the value (even by the browser)

Comment: Thank you for that suggestion. It is the height that I am concerned with, and the height is to be dynamically determined by the height of the content in a sibling cell. This works fine in Chrome but not in Internet Explorer.

Comment: maybe its a margin or padding thing try adding margin:0px !important; and padding:0px !important;